# List columns in data frame that have missing values as '?'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

List names of the column(s) of data frame along with the count of missing number of values if missing values are coded with '?' using pandas and numpy.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

bridgeall = pd.read_excel('bridge.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
#print(bridgeall)


bridge_sep = bridgeall.iloc[:,0].str.split(',',-1,expand=True)
bridge_sep.columns = ['IDENTIF','RIVER', 'LOCATION', 'ERECTED', 'PURPOSE', 'LENGTH', 'LANES','CLEAR-G', 'T-OR-D',
                     'MATERIAL', 'SPAN', 'REL-L', 'TYPE']

print(bridge_sep)
```

Data: I am posting a snippet. Its actually [107 rows x 13 columns].

```
    IDENTIF RIVER LOCATION   ERECTED    ...    MATERIAL    SPAN REL-L      TYPE
0        E2     A       ?    CRAFTS    ...        WOOD   SHORT     ?     WOOD
1        E3     A       39    CRAFTS    ...        WOOD       ?     S      WOOD
2        E5     A       ?    CRAFTS    ...        WOOD   SHORT     S      WOOD
```

Output required:

```
LOCATION 2
SPAN 1
REL-L 1
```

Comment: What's your data and what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare all values by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`) and for count accurencies use `sum` - `True`s are processes like `1`, then remove only `False` values (`0`) by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.eq('?').sum()
s = s[s != 0]
print (s)
LOCATION    2
SPAN        1
REL-L       1
dtype: int64
```

Last for `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = s.reset_index()
df1.columns = ['names','count']
print (df1)
      names  count
0  LOCATION      2
1      SPAN      1
2     REL-L      1
```

EDIT:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4

#compare with same length Series 
#same index values like index/columns of DataFrame
s = pd.Series(np.arange(5))
print (s)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int32
```

---

```
#compare columns
print (df.eq(s, axis=0))
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2   True   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4   True  False  False  False   True

#compare rows
print (df.eq(s, axis=1))
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1   True  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False   True  False   True   True
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. :)

Comment: Documenation? I need to understand the operational difference between `eq` and `==`.

Comment: @user10089194 - [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) function is more general, also less `()` in writing code. You can also compare by Series per rows or per columns with `axis=1` or `axis=0` parameters.

Comment: @user10089194 Edited answer with explanation.

Comment: If I want the other way around? That is print column names and values that do not have '?'.Is there a negate for `eq` I remember you said to use ~ in one of my earlier question so I tried these in case they worked but got error. `cv = ~(bridge_sep.eq('?').sum())` or `cv = bridge_sep.eq(~'?').sum()` This one works though `cv = bridge_sep.count() - bridge_sep.eq('?').sum()`

Comment: @user10089194 - Change `eq` to [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)

Comment: `cv = bridge_sep.ne('?').sum() `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183825/discussion-between-user10089194-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame is named `df`, try `(df == '?').sum()`

Comment: And how can I print the name of column alongside as well? Is there any code in Pandas for that? I know how to print the columns name but I need [column-name,sum of ? values in that column]

Comment: Are the column names not already being printed as the index of the resulting sum? What specific data are you using and what specific output are you getting?